# Need help in T SQL query in Azure Stream Analytics

Tags: t-sql, azure-stream-analytics

I am working in streaming of data by using Azure Stream analytics job which will use T SQL Query. I Have the following Requirement:

[image]

I can do it by using `case` and `sum` statements, but I have lot of countries and issues (L3), so is there any pivot option I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can query using pivot as below:

```
Select * from (
    Select Co_nm, TimePeriod, CONCAT(L3, ISO_Cntry_Nm) as L3Country, [No of issues] 
        from #yourtable
        ) a
pivot (max([No of issues]) for L3Country in ([Issue 1Great Britain], [Issue 1India],[Issue 1America],[Issue 2Great Britain], [Issue 2India],[Issue 2America] ) ) p
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but i have No.of combinations of L3 and Countries so isthere any approach like Shape in R program , i can get with formula?

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way is using collect() to get an array of events, and pass it to a JavaScript UDF to do the pivot.

```
WITH EventCollection AS 
(
  SELECT collect() AS allEvents
  FROM input TIMESTAMP BY timeperiod
  GROUP BY System.Timestamp
),
PivotRecord AS
(
  SELECT udf.getPivotRecord(allEvents) AS record
  FROM EventCollection 
)
SELECT record.*
INTO output
FROM PivotRecord
```

For example JavaScript UDF that handles array, see this blog post [Using Azure Stream Analytics JavaScript UDF to lookup values in JSON array](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/streamanalytics/2017/04/04/using-azure-stream-analytics-javascript-udf-to-lookup-values-in-json-array/).

Comment: Thanks for the solution but , i have zero knowledge on JAVA , so it would be better if i use T sql , im looking for SImilar function like CAST in R program but in TSQL